# Jenkins Pipeline env.JAVA_HOME differs from sh printenv

Tags: java, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Jenkins 2.2024.2
Kubernetes Plugin 1.22.0

The `env.JAVA_HOME` variable is getting set to a different value than what `sh 'printenv'` shows. I had thought `env` was a reflection of the environment. I also can't find where `env.JAVA_HOME` is set. It doesn't reflect the value in the Global JDK configurations. I also grepped the Jenkins Master root directory for openjdk and only found the correct value.

```
bash-4.4# grep openjdk *
config.xml:      <home>/usr/local/openjdk-8/jre</home>
```

Here's a pipeline demonstrating the behavior.

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        kubernetes { label 'java8-mvn3' }
    }

    stages {
        stage('test') {
            steps {
                container ('java8-mvn3') {
                    echo env.JAVA_HOME
                    echo "++++++++++++++++++++++++++"
                    sh 'printenv | grep JAVA_HOME'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

** OUTPUT **

```
[Pipeline] echo
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk
[Pipeline] echo
++++++++++++++++++++++++++
[Pipeline] sh
+ printenv
+ grep JAVA_HOME
JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/openjdk-8
```

Comment: Just try `sh "printenv | grep JAVA_HOME"` with double quotations.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @hariK . The commands are working properly in the pipeline. My confusion is why does env.JAVA_HOME have a different value from the printenv JAVA_HOME.

Comment: Print $SHELL and see if it is using other than the one used by normal logon to machine. If they are different override `Shell executable` in Global Jenkins configuration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JAVA_HOME environment variable is set based on the Jenkins Master's environment. While the `printenv` shows the environment variables of the slave container.

Answer (score 0):

As per man page : http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/printenv.1.html

> ```
>    NOTE: your shell may have its own version of printenv, which usually
>    supersedes the version described here.  Please refer to your shell's
>    documentation for details about the options it supports.
> ```

So you many need to go with specific shell with something like `sh '''#!/bin/bash -c ...`

Or as an another option export the one needed at global / stage definition environment level